# Present view underneath another

Tags: swift

I'm trying to pop up a view controller from the bottom of the screen but I want a view from its parent view controller to show on top of it so that it slides up from underneath this view. There's no interactivity with this extra view on top of everything. Is there a reasonably simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve this:

You can create a xib and add over the view controller.

You also create a programmatically view and add over the VC.

You also can drag view over the VC in storyboard and initially hide the view.

Show with the animation.